# Java test with mongodb database

Tags: java, mongodb, unit-testing, testing, junit5

### Description

I am testing a bulk insert in a mobgoDB database, in the `@BeforeEach` method I instantiate the database, in the`@AfterEach` I delete all documents created in the *puzzles-today* collection.

But the last one always fails, have random result, sometimes the test passes sometimes it displays this 367 or 366 or 364 or 364.

I added `@RepeatedTest(4)` To make sure it doesn't vary.

### The code :

#### Class test

```java
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

import java.util.List;

import com.github.mathieusoysal.codingame_stats.CodinGame;
import com.github.mathieusoysal.codingame_stats.puzzle.Puzzle;

import org.bson.Document;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.RepeatedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import io.github.mathieusoysal.util.MongoDBMockTest;

public class PuzzleDaoTest extends MongoDBMockTest {

    private PuzzlesDao puzzleDao;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        puzzleDao = new PuzzlesDao(mongoClient, "CodinGame-stats");
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        mongoClient.getDatabase("CodinGame-stats")
                .getCollection(PuzzlesDao.PUZZLES_HISTORY_COLLECTION)
                .deleteMany(new Document());
        super.tearDown();
    }

    @Test
    void testSaveAll_shouldReturnTrue_withTwoPuzzles() {
        List<Puzzle> puzzles = new CodinGame().getPuzzles().subList(0, 2);
        assertTrue(puzzleDao.saveAll(puzzles));
    }

    @Test
    void testSaveAll_shouldAugmentCollectionSize_withTwoPuzzles() {
        List<Puzzle> puzzles = new CodinGame().getPuzzles().subList(0, 2);
        puzzleDao.saveAll(puzzles);
        assertEquals(puzzles.size(), countDocuments());
    }

    @RepeatedTest(4)
    void testSaveAll_shouldAugmentCollectionSize_withAllPuzzles() {
        List<Puzzle> puzzles = new CodinGame().getPuzzles();
        puzzleDao.saveAll(puzzles);
        assertEquals(puzzles.size(), countDocuments());
    }

    private long countDocuments() {
        return mongoClient.getDatabase("CodinGame-stats")
                .getCollection(PuzzlesDao.PUZZLES_HISTORY_COLLECTION)
                .countDocuments();
    }

}
```

### Clone the project

To easily replicate this, you can clone the repository in the `dev` branch https://github.com/MathieuSoysal/CodinGame-Puzzles-stats-saver/tree/dev

### Error displayed :

[image]

But this result is random, sometimes the test passes sometimes it displays a error.

anyone have any idea to fix this?

Comment: There’s too much unknown stuff going on here. I suggest you create a minimum example with all details to replicate your problem. Otherwise it’s hard to figure it out for outside people.

Comment: @johanneslink Thank for your feed-back, I added more details to replicate the problem.

Comment: What’s the failure message?

Comment: I edited my question to add the failure message.

Comment: Looks to me as if deleteMany does not work as expected. You could try to drop the collection in tearDown instead.

Comment: BTW, you still don’t have a reproducible example since I cannot run the code without additional assumptions. Eg the CodingGame class could produce any set of puzzles with overlapping IDs etc etc. If you’re not able to reduce the example so that all the relevant code fits reasonably into the question, you should provide a public repo on Github or alike so that anyone can just clone and try. Everything else is pure poking around and spitting out random ideas.

Comment: The CodinGame class comes from the `codingame-puzzles-stats` library, if you want to replicate the example you need to clone the `pom.xml` as well.

Comment: If you want to raise chances that somebody will help figure out your problem, make replicating the issue for them as easy as possible. Having to put my own pom.xml together and copying several sources into a project that I have to configure myself is way beyond my threshold. Other people‘s mileage may vary.

Comment: @johanneslink Really thank you for your feedback, I redit the question, and I added a link to the GitHub project.

Comment: Cool! I could checkout the project in dev branch, import it into IntelliJ and run PuzzleDaoTest. What I observe is that PuzzleDaoTest.testSaveAll_shouldAugmentCollectionSize_withAllPuzzles always fails, even if I run it just once. So you achieved simple reproducibility! I'll have a look at the underlying problem later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is not a test problem, but an implementation problem.
Look at:

```java
class PuzzlesDao...
    public boolean saveAll(List<Puzzle> puzzles) {
        List<WriteModel<Document>> bulkWrites = new ArrayList<>();
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = builder.create();
        puzzles.parallelStream()
                .forEach(puzzle -> bulkWrites.add(new InsertOneModel<>(Document.parse(gson.toJson(puzzle)))));
        BulkWriteOptions bulkWriteOptions = new BulkWriteOptions().ordered(false);
        BulkWriteResult bulkWriteResult = collection.bulkWrite(bulkWrites, bulkWriteOptions);
        return bulkWriteResult.wasAcknowledged();
    }
```

You are using `parallelStream()` without a closing operation like `collect(..)` or `count()`. The forEach code is still being executed while the bulk operation is already running. Thus the resulting behaviour is unpredictable. One heuristic is to never use any side-effects in `forEach()`. If you have to then using a simple for loop is the better choice in my opinion.

I recommend the following change:

```java
public boolean saveAll(List<Puzzle> puzzles) {
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    Gson gson = builder.create();
    List<WriteModel<Document>> bulkWrites =
            puzzles.parallelStream()
                    .map(puzzle -> new InsertOneModel<>(Document.parse(gson.toJson(puzzle))))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    BulkWriteOptions bulkWriteOptions = new BulkWriteOptions().ordered(false);
    BulkWriteResult bulkWriteResult = collection.bulkWrite(bulkWrites, bulkWriteOptions);
    return bulkWriteResult.wasAcknowledged();
}
```

I personally hardly ever use `parallelStream()` unless I can show that it improves performance in a worthwhile way, which it usually does not.
Using just `stream()` gets rid of the intricacies of parallelism.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

I just changed `.toList()` instead of `.collect(Collectors.toList())`.